# How to login to windows using a database

Tags: database, windows, oracle, authentication, windows-10

I've been looking through the internet for a solution for my problem but I can't find it, maybe I'm looking in the wrong places.

The deal is there's this oracle database with personal information, everyone has an id and a password. I have to make a program, or add a functionality to windows that allows people to login with their information into the library computers, so for example, Carl, enters his ID and his password in the login page of windows of any computer (There are computers with windows 10 and 8 by the way) and he can start using the pc. I also have to keep the timestamps of each person entering the computers. Basically that's it.

I wanna know if there's a way to make windows read this database to login users instead of the default one, I remember seeing this system in my university. Or if I have to create a whole software to keep track of this, and if so where can I get information of how to do it. Thank you for your time.

Comment: This is usually done via LDAP / Active Directory...
It is not possible on normal ways to perform your wanted tasks at all since that would break windows security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is a 'credential provider' replacement that interfaces with your database. pgina (http://pgina.org/) for instance supports mysql backends (among other solutions).